# How import custom class in controller Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a new directory `Library` in root of Laravel.

Inside I put the file with class:

`class My {
  //
}`

So, in controller Laravel I try to get access to this class:

```
App\Library\My
```

But Laravel does not determine this path.

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use View;

use App\Library\My;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
 //
}
```

Comment: Did you use `psr-4` if not run `composer dump-autoload` !

Comment: It did not help: `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As above, make sure it is placed in the App directory and make sure it is properly namespaced e.g.

```
<?php
  $fOne = new \App\library\functions;
  $isOk = ($fOne->isOk());
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

A complete and functional example based on the posts here:

1 - **Folder and file** - Create a folder under `app/`, in this example we will create a folder called `Library`.

We will also inside the folder create a file with the name of your class, here we will create a class called `My`.

So we will have `app/Library/My.php`

2 - **Class and method** -  Now, for testing, inside the class create a static method called `myMethod`

```
<?php

namespace App\Library;

class My
{
    public static function myMethod() 
    {
        return 'it\'s work!';
    }
}
```

3 - **Controller** - Now at the beginning of the Controller, we will declare the namespace of your Class with `use`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Library\My;

//rest of the controller code
```

Finally, to create an instance of the `My` class, in Controller, a `new` statement must be used:

```
//rest of the controller code

public function index()
{ 
    $whatever = new My;
    return $whatever::myMethod();
}
```

Comment: I like how elaborate your answer is.

Answer (score 2):

You should create `Library` folder inside `app` folder

`namespace App\Library\My`

`app` folder is alrdy used `psr-4`

In your controller

`use App\Library\My as My`

It's work for me. Hope this answer is helpful

Comment: If when I want to use some namespaces?

Comment: If you want use another namespace without app like `Library\My` look at file `composer.json` at `autoload` > `psr-4`. Insert new your custom autoload and run `composer dump-autoload` in `terminal`

Comment: When I mouse over this ` 
use App\Library\My;` I get message: undefined namespace

Answer (score 2):

You have to properly namespace your every class.

So you can import your class with `use` keyword, like so

```
use App\Library\My;

....

$my = new My();
```

Or if you've conflicting class name then you can use `as` keyword to alias the classname while importing

```
use App\Library\My as MySecond;

....

$my = new MySecond();
```

And if you want to directly access your class within the method then you can access it like so.

```
$my = new \App\Library\My();
```

**Note:** The leading `\` means App was declared in the global scope.

Comment: `use App\Library\My;` - undefined namespace

Comment: @Dev show me the code of your class and where you are trying to access the class?

Comment: May be I should to use provider?

Comment: Don´t mix it with java `import`. Unfortunetely php´s `use` does not import anything. It just refers to some namespace or class-name.